# Decrypt file only when opened (double click)

Tags: encryption

I would like to have all my sensitive documents on my local network NAS and let my operating system only decrypt a file when opened / double clicked.
How to do this?

Comment: You can do this on Mac with encrypted disk images [though you still have to put them away again afterwards, or reboot]. idk about other OSes.

Comment: Cryptomator maybe? I'm not sure if it will work with a NAS.

Comment: cryptomator encrypts folders or multiple files altogether. Also in practice one has to decrypt the whole folder or set of files to use them. I want all of the files encrypted and decrypt only the file which i would like to open. I am happy to type in my password again and again to open each file.

Comment: It would be helpful to specify which OS this would be for. If it turns out that there is not a native way, maybe the Software Recommendations SE would have a solution. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i am using macOs. But in worst case i am able to accept linux.

Comment: You could possibly use password protected archives.  Then use something like [this script](https://superuser.com/a/1823815/788170) to mount & access them, and clean up when finished.