# Output of atool -l for large archives

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

The command `atool -l my_archive` prints the directory structure and files of `my_archive` to the command line. This is very handy if the archive contains only a few files. However, if there are many files and directories, the output quickly becomes confusing.

Is there a way to "control" this output, e.g. show only files and directories of the top level?

I am also willing to switch to another command, if necessary. Ideally, I would like to have a command that, by default, only prints the files and directories of the top level and allows me to navigate (using autocompletion) into subdirectories. Example: Say `my_archive` contains folder A and file f at the top level, and A has subdirectories B and C. Then

```
atool -l my_archive
```

should print A and f (I should be able to tell from the output that A is a directory). If I want to inspect A, I would type

```
atool -l my_archive/A
```

and it should print B and C.

Does something like this exist or is it possible to tweak `atool -l` in way that the above is possible?

Edit: Here is an example of `atool -l` output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       143 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/.htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       213 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/README
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       178 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/autoload.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      7255 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/aziraphale/email-address-validator/EmailAddressValidator.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      2624 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/aziraphale/email-address-validator/README.md
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012     13459 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      1070 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      2532 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       451 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_files.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       310 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012       380 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      2476 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012      4892 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
-rw-r--r-- 2012/2012     16994 2020-07-29 11:35 dokuwiki/vendor/composer/installed.json
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168812/108618

Comment: I suppose my_archive is a compressed file of some type, zip or tar.gz, etc? And `atool` displays it's contents, like `tree` or `ls`?

Comment: I added an example output. In fact, the way tree or ls outputs is what I would like to have

Comment: `atool -l your_archive | tree --fromfile .`

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a little bit messing around.

```
atool -l your_archive | tree --fromfile .
```

This seemed like all you really needed, but these extra's constitutes an answer.

```
atool *zip | tree --fromfile . | awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; print "" }'
```

You can really customize your output with `awk` columns. Taking off the initial `tree` branches, starting on column 2, helps greatly on output.

The filenames usually span quite a few columns, so `NF` just goes to the last one.  You could easily truncate long filenames changing the `NF` to a column number. e.g. `(i = 2; i <= 8; i++)`

If you a really want to get into it, fully customizable, you can use `-J` to output to JSON.

```
als *tar | tree --fromfile . -J
```

```
[
  {"type":"directory","name":".","contents":[
    {"type":"directory","name":"drwxr-xr-x jason","contents":[
      {"type":"directory","name":"jason       0 2023-06-06 16:03 0n_git","contents":[
## truncated for brevity ##
      ]},
      {"type":"directory","name":"jason     282 2023-06-06 15:31 0n_git","contents":[
        {"type":"directory","name":"shellscripts","contents":[
          {"type":"file","name":"sshot.sh"}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]}
  {"type":"report","directories":26,"files":9}
]
```

You could then use `jq` and `pup`.  Your possibilities would be endless.  You could even incorporate [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) to output to a template.

---

I read the post on [Kamil Maciorowski's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1823134/output-of-atool-l-for-large-archives#comment2870043_1823134) and expanded on it.

Install `archivemount` & `nnn` from the repository.  This is exactly what you are after:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check file argument is not empty 
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <archive_file>"
    exit 1
fi

# prepare file for mount
archive_file="$1"
unique_id=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)
mount_point="/tmp/archive-$unique_id"
mkdir -p "$mount_point"

# mount archive
archivemount "$archive_file" "$mount_point" -o readonly -o auto_unmount -o auto_cache

# browse archive using nnn & cleanup on exit
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    nnn "$mount_point"
    fusermount -u "$mount_point"
    rmdir "$mount_point"
else
    echo "Failed to mount the archive."
fi

exit 0
```

Save to: `archive_explore.sh`
Change mode to executable: `chmod +x archive_explore.sh`
Usage: `./archive_explore.sh your_archive`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That should make sense.  My fault.

Comment: Nice job! You explained it much better now and provided very useful details.